# Increase contrast of image using ImageJ library (Java)

Tags: java, image, image-manipulation, imagej

I am trying to increase the contrast of an image by some factor `x`

So far I am able to read in an image, and get its processor like this

```
ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus(imagePathHere);
ImageProcessor ip = im.getProcessor();
```

I am aware of `ContrastEnhancer.java` and `ContrastAdjuster.java` but I am not sure how they would be used. 
Ultimately, I would want something like this

```
ImagePlus imc = increaseContrast(im, 0.5)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus(imagePathHere);
ContrastEnhancer enh = new ContrastEnhancer();
enh.stretchHistogram(plus, i);
```

where i < 100;

When you call

```
im.getImage();
```

you will get an image with increased contrast.

Comment: Hmm. Yes this does seem to work. However, it's not doing what I want it to do. An increase in the contrast in Photoshop does not show the same effect as this method. Do you think it's maybe in `ContrastAdjuster` I'll play around with it ?

Comment: I think ContrastAdjuster is just a graphical component for the standalone ImageJ application. If you wish you could download both the source and the standalone and see how the contrast adjustments work in their app.

Comment: There's a method `adjustContrast` in `ContrastAdjuster.java`. Any idea what this is doing?

Comment: I'm looking at the ImageJ api and I'm not seeing a single "adjustContrast" method. http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming because it's not a public method. Check out [the source code](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/source/ij/plugin/frame/ContrastAdjuster.java.html). It's in there

Answer (score 1):

```
setMinAndMax(double min, double max)
```

on the [ImageProcessor](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/) object.